# append div to text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a text area and I'm attempting to append a div to it. I'm trying to do it with Jquery like this...

```
var text = '<div class="item"><a class="as">q</a>test</div>';
$('#textArea').append(text);
```

The code runs without throwing any errors but my text doesn't appear inside the textarea. Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you want to put text inside your textarea, or do you want to insert a div element after it?

Comment: @mack Won't work. Try it before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add it to the HTML structure or simply show the HTML Code as text ?
If you want to add it to the textarea HTML structure this will not work.
What you are searching for is
`$('#textArea').text(text);` or `$('#textArea').text($('#textArea').text()+text);`

`.text()` sets text of your textArea
 `.html()` would set your html Content

Answer (score 0):

You can't append to a textarea. Its text content behaves like other input.

```
var text = '<div class="item"><a class="as">q</a>test</div>';
$('#textArea').val( $('#textArea').val() + text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#textArea').val(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't** want to render the div's contents but simply want to display the HTML inside the textarea you need to convert the HTML first:

```
var lt='&lt;';
var gt='&gt;';
var text = '<div class="item"><a class="as">q</a>test</div>';
text = text.replace(/</gi, lt);
text = text.replace(/>/gi, gt);
$('#textArea').append(text);
```

And the HTML for the text area should look like this:

```
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
```

If you **do** want to render the div's contents inside the textarea use:

```
var text = '<div class="item"><a class="as">q</a>test</div>';
$('#textArea').append(text);
```

The HTML for the text area is the same as in the other example:

```
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put div in textarea but sometimes you need to do so. Good news is that you can do it in other way by using **contenteditable** property of elements. Like

```
 <div contenteditable="true" style="min-height:50px; width:300px;" id="txtDiv">
 </div>
```

This Div will behave exactly like a Textarea but you can append anything you want. And remember when you want to grab data from inside it in jquery

```
 var ContentofDiv = $('#txtDiv').html();
```